# how to show months and years from two date in PHP

Tags: php, datediff, between

I have `$date1 = '2014-09-01'` and `$date2 = '2015-02-01'`. Can I get months and years from `$date1` to `$date2` like this:

- 2014-sep
- 2014-oct
- 2014-nov
- 2014-dec
- 2015-jan
- 2015-feb

Comment: Have you tried coding something yourself already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2014-09-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2015-02-01");

while ($date1 <= $date2) {

    echo $date1->format("Y-M")."\n";
    $date1->modify("+1 month");
}
```

Result:

```
2014-Sep
2014-Oct
2014-Nov
2014-Dec
2015-Jan
2015-Feb
```

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate [`DateTime`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects and loop through them:

```
$date1 = new \DateTime('2014-09-01');
$date2 = new \DateTime('2015-02-01');

while ($date1 <= $date2) {
    echo $date1->format('Y-M') . '<br>';
    $date1->add(new \DateInterval('P1M')); // increase by one month
}
```

Result:

```
2014-Sep
2014-Oct
2014-Nov
2014-Dec
2015-Jan
2015-Feb
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)  class with couple of methods like add() to increment counter and format() to date formating using simple while loop

```
$startDate= new DateTime("2014-09-01");
$endDate = new DateTime("2015-02-01");
$oneMonth=new DateInterval('P1M');      //for 1 month interval

while ($startDate <= $endDate) {
  print $startDate->format("Y-M")."\n";  //date formating as your requirement
  $startDate->add($oneMonth);          //increment counter by 1 month
 }
```